# Error while installing mysql-server in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql

```
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This error is coming while installing this.
I am using the following command to install:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

I have also tried purging/removing the complete package, starting and stopping services, autoclean, autoremove. Everything. Kindly help me in installing mysql-server and client.

Answer (score 1):

try removing it with following commands:

```
sudo apt-get --auto-remove purge mysql\*
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get --auto-remove purge mysql\*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql* /var/lib/mysql* /usr/share/mysql* /var/log/mysql
sudo apt-get clean
```

see if it was cleaned up properly

```
sudo updatedb
locate mysql
```

and scan the output for folders, packages or files left over from the uninstalling.

after making sure those are gone, too, re-install it cleanly:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client
```